# How to replace hard-coded indexes with variables that work with different datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I'd love some advice on how I can abide by the rule saying that my code has to work for any data. I tried to use indexing to find the biggest loss date for the question below, it didn't work. I ended up just hard coding the dates into the 'losshigh' variable, but I don't think that's sufficient. We also can't use for loops.

The 'stock' dataset we are working with is a pandas Series with a DateTime index and float values.

"Find the worst buy and sell date combo, aka. the two days where the percent lost when purchasing  x and selling in y (with y after x) is maximized."
*Hint:* Use method cummax() or method cummin().

Here is what I have so far.

====

```
#Reproducing stock.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('NVDA.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
stock = data['Close']
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

====

```
#Find the highest index of x that comes before the lowest index of y

#The worst ratio of high stock in the past to whatever stock price is now.
bigloss=stock.cummax()/stock
biggestloss=bigloss.nlargest(1)

#Defining y.
y=stock.loc[biggestloss.index]

#The highest stock up to the biggest loss date.
losshigh=stock.loc['1999-01-22':'2002-10-09'].max()

#Defining x.
x=stock[stock==losshigh]

#The worst percentage.
percentage=(x[0]-y[0]/x[0])*100
```

Comment: Hi Jojo! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry to hear you've been having such a bad time with it. Please don't burn yourself out/give yourself mental problems over coding, it's not the end of the world if you're struggling with a problem. Please take care of yourself first

Comment: can you edit your question to add the code for reproducing `stock` please?

Comment: also what would be helpful right now? Hints, guidance, the answer straight up? I could understand if in your situation if you were sick and tired of the question and just wanted an answer (though, generally speaking, on here we try not to just give people the answers to homework questions, as the whole point of homework (and education) is for the student to learn

Comment: You first need to separate the logical process problem from the coding problem. With some sample data and paper/pen think through how you would work out the required result by hand. Then capture this logical process in code so that it works on a data set of any size. If the code gives error messages or does not produce the expected result to match your paper workings then explore what is going wrong.

Comment: @Mark Updated! At this point, definitely the answer. I've tried everything in my skillset, I've tried everything that was taught in class. At this point, I'm just burning time that should be used for studying for my other class's midterms. The answer would help me see what I could have done differently. I understand the point of not giving people the answers to homework questions when they haven't tried everything, but at this point I'm overwhelmed, exhausted, and don't have time to work on this question further. I imagine the answer is some combo of commands I don't know how to use. Thanks.

Comment: "*I've tried so many things and feel like I've been banging my head against the wall with no progress for hours*". Well, you already know what programming is like then. Do not give up, you will break the wall.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a ton for your help. I had no idea .idxmin() and .idxmax() could be used in that way, even after reading the documentation for it yesterday. I'll definitely never forget it can be used in this way after all the struggle.

Comment: no worries! glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so first a disclaimer: I interpreted this as what is the maximum total loss you can make from buying on one day, and selling on another. The tutors could be asking for the maximum loss per day from buying and selling, or the max percentage loss, or max percentage loss per day, but those are different problems.

But anyway:

```
# first, we import pandas
import pandas as pd

# second, create sample data
stock = pd.Series([100, 120, 90, 30, 70, 150, 110, 100, 80, 90], index=pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=10, freq='D'), name='Stock_Price')

# cummax() finds the minimum value in the data *so far*
>>> stock.cummax()
2023-01-01    100
2023-01-02    120
2023-01-03    120
2023-01-04    120
2023-01-05    120
2023-01-06    150
2023-01-07    150
2023-01-08    150
2023-01-09    150
2023-01-10    150
```

So basically, here's the idea: if on a particular day, the difference between the cummax and the stock price of that day is large, it means that we could have bought it in the past, at the higher price , and then sold it today. If the price today is lower than that maximum, then we'll lose money. Here is the results for our dataset:

```
>>> stock - stock.cummax() 
2023-01-01     0
2023-01-02     0
2023-01-03   -30
2023-01-04   -90
2023-01-05   -50
2023-01-06     0
2023-01-07   -40
2023-01-08   -50
2023-01-09   -70
2023-01-10   -60
```

Now, we can see just by looking, the worst day to sell would be on 2023-01-04. We can get that value by using idxmin():

```
>>> sell_day = (stock - stock.cummax()).idxmin()
Timestamp('2023-01-04 00:00:00')
```

Now to get the data points from the beginning to the selling day, and then finding the highest price within those days, which has to be our buying day:

```
>>> stock[:sell_day]
2023-01-01    100
2023-01-02    120
2023-01-03     90
2023-01-04     30

>>> buy_day = stock.loc[:sell_day].idxmax()
Timestamp('2023-01-02 00:00:00')
```

Now finally, to get the loss, we can calculate that using simple arithmetic:

```
>>> 100 * (stock[sell_day] - stock[buy_day]) / stock[sell_day]
-300.0
```

In the example dataset, you'd lose 300% by buying on 2023-01-02 at $120, and selling on 2023-01-04 at $30.